# A better understanding of the relations between database tables

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to get a better understanding of relational databases and there is something that I keep bumping into and don't understand. Let's take this two tables:

[image]

In this case `Login.ID` is the primary key with `auto_increment` set and `Profile.ID_LOGIN` is the foreign key. When a user is created and its username and password are stored in the `login` database does the `ID` corresponding to the current username and password get automatically added into `ID_LOGIN` or do I have to create a SQL statement to do this?

If I have to create a SQL statement how should I approach adding the `ID_LOGIN` to make sure I am adding it correctly?

Comment: mysql is not SQL Server. Pick one.

Comment: I udnerstand thaat they are not the same but this concept applyes to both corect me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, having a foreign key is just a field in one table which is a place to store a reference to a record in another table.  So your code has to populate both tables and set the foreign key.

Databases have features for foreign key constraints, which are helpful to forbid database operations which would leave a foreign key where there is no record in the other table referenced by the value in the foreign key.

The really handy thing about maintaining a foreign key in an SQL database is that you can easily do a join to get the related data when you need it in a query.

BTW, Ruby on Rails manages foreign keys for you using associations.  So if you program in Ruby on Rails, it will set the foreign keys for you and often do the joins you need.

Answer (score 1):

you should create SQL statement to add record into Profile table. FK constraint does not allow you to add ID_LOGIN which is not in Login table, so you don't have to check it manually.

Answer (score 1):

when you insert a row into a tbale with a foreign key, you have to make sure in advance, that the value you are trying to insert into the foreign key column exists in the linked table.

In other words: When you try to insert a row into Profile with ID_LOGIN set to 25 for example and no row exists in the Login table with ID 25 you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be added automatically.
You have to add it using create statement.If you want it to be automatically added then you have to create trigger with Login table.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Profile record, you will need to ensure that you have linked the correct Login record.

For instance, for a person called John Smith who gets an email of jsmith@thecompany.com and has a user/pass combination of johns/password

`Insert into Profile 
values ('John Smith', jsmith@thecompany.com, (select ID from Login where user = jsmith))`

will create a profile that links back to your Login record.

Answer (score 1):

You will always have to create an SQL query to add it to the Profile table. But perhaps using procedures/triggers/functions you might be able to create a query that allows you to add it as soon as a line is added in the Login table.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add data to both tables (two insert statements). First you insert the User and get its autogenerated ID. Then you can insert your Profile record using the user_id you got in the first insert.

That said, you are describing a *One to Many* relation (a User could have several Profiles) but a relation between Users and Profiles should be *One to One*, because each User always has only one Profile, and each Profile corresponds to only one User.